# Why wont my ARM assembly program print anything using C printf

Tags: assembly, arm

So i'm calling the printf function in ARM from gcc to print stuff out from my registers.

Here is my code:

```
.global main
.global printf
.global fopen
.global fclose
.global fgetc

main:
    @ Open File
    PUSH {R1} @ Push address of R1 onto stack
    LDR R0, [R1, #0x04] @ Get argv[1] from stack to R0
    LDR R1, =r @ Load address of file open format (read)
    BL fopen @ Open file
    LDR R1, =fin @ Load address of file in to R1
    STR R0, [R1] @ Store contents of R1 into R0

    @ Setup array
    LDR R4, =ch_array @ Array address
    MOV R3, #0 @ Array index

    BL loopFile
    BL printArray

@ Loop through the file
loopFile:
    LDR R1, =fin @ Load R1 with address of file in
    LDR R0, [R1] @ Load R0 with pointer? of R1
    BL fgetc @ Get next character from file into R0?
    CMP R0, #-1 @ Check for end of file
    BEQ endl @ Close file

    @ get index from character (fgetc)
    /*
        Assuming the base address is in R4 (my array), the ascii is in R0
        from the file input into R0: increment the word in memory at
        the address 'R4 + (R0 * 4)'. *4 because each word is 4 bytes.
    */
    LSL R0, R0, #2
    LDR R1, [R4, R0]
    ADD R1, R1, #1
    STR R1, [R4, R0]

    B loopFile @ Run loop again

@ Close the file
endl:
    LDR R1, =fin @ Load R1 with address of file in
    LDR R0, [R1] @ Load R0 with pointer? of R1
    BL fclose @ Close the file

printArray:
    CMP R3, #ARRAY_MAX @ while (i < ARRAY_MAX)
    BEQ _exit @ Exit if max

    @ Check if value of the array at index i where
    @ (i = character number) is 0, if so then skip it
    @ else print it

    @ R3 counter of array
    @ R4 array address

    LDR R0, =printa @ Load print format
    MOV R1, R3 @ Store character value (index of array) in R1
    LDR R2, [R4, R3] @ Load count of index R3
    CMP R2, #0 @ Check if count is 0
    BEQ printArray @ If count is 0, skip
    BL printf @ Else print
    ADD R3, R3, #1 @ Increment R3 ('i')
    B printArray @ Loop next iteration of array

@ End program
_exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    MOV R0, #0
    SWI 0

.data
    .equ ARRAY_MAX, 255
    ch_array:
        .rept ARRAY_MAX @For all elements in array, repeat:
        .word 0x00 @Initialize to 0
        .endr @End repetition
    fin:   .word 0x00
    printa: .asciz "%d : %d\n"
    r:     .asciz "r"
    space: .asciz " "
    nl:    .asciz "\n"
```

However, Nothing is printed to the screen. There are no errors or anything, no segmentation faults. I'm loading the arguments correctly so I can't seem to figure out where im going wrong!

Thanks

Comment: Not related to C, but the system library.

Comment: @Olaf it asys `Program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault. 0x76ef2c09 in getc() from .../libc.so.6.`

Comment: None of your functions seem to return. Nor do they save the old `LR` if they call other functions.

Comment: @Michael what do you mean they don't seem to return?

Comment: Well, do you understand what the `BL` instruction does in terms of the registers it modifies? Now, based on that, what does a function need to do to get back to where it was called from (because the CPU certainly doesn't figure that out for you by itself)?

Comment: @Michael using `B fnc` ?

Comment: @Michael is right. `main` for example does not even return, but just advances into `loopFile`. And the LR is not saved before calling another function. Maybe you have some missconception what an assembler label is? Hint: it does not emit code like a function definition does for entry and return.

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: Sorry, stack overflow is not a tutorial site. You seem to lack some of the basics; until then, it is useless to analyse the code. (No offence!)